# GWT on Firefox: "Negative entryDepth value at exit -1"

Tags: firefox, gwt

When using GWT 2.8.0 on Firefox 50.0.2, I get the error `Error: java.lang.AssertionError: Negative entryDepth value at entry -1` in the Firefox console whenever a new window is opened. This happens both when running and when debugging in development mode It occurs from Eclipse using the GWT plugin as well as from the command line with `maven gwt:run`. On Google Chrome 55.0.2883.75 this error does not occur.

It does not give me the Java code that caused it as it is compiled into Javascript. The exact description is:

```
16:48:21.741 Error: java.lang.AssertionError: Negative entryDepth value at entry -1 1 6D7CBA4ECA4CC73438AFEBFA72E95084.cache.js:9149:10
    JC_g$ triplecheckmate-0.js
    TC_g$ triplecheckmate-0.js
    DC_g$ triplecheckmate-0.js
    Z$d_g$ triplecheckmate-0.js
    h_d_g$ triplecheckmate-0.js
    Spc_g$ triplecheckmate-0.js
    zL_g$ triplecheckmate-0.js
    BL_g$ triplecheckmate-0.js
    AL_g$/< triplecheckmate-0.js
    EventLoop.prototype.enter resource://devtools/server/actors/script.js:348:5
    bound  self-hosted
    ThreadActor<._pushThreadPause resource://devtools/server/actors/script.js:531:5
    ThreadActor<._pauseAndRespond resource://devtools/server/actors/script.js:739:7
    ThreadActor<.onDebuggerStatement resource://devtools/server/actors/script.js:1817:9
    bound  self-hosted
    CL_g$ triplecheckmate-0.js
    BL_g$ triplecheckmate-0.js
    AL_g$/< triplecheckmate-0.js
```

I found a similar issue mentioned without a fix in https://github.com/kyoken74/gwt-angular/issues/73 from 2014 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=321880 from 2015.

Comment: There was an issue for the GWT project: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/7923. It looks like, that this was/is a FireFox bug

Comment: Thanks for the link! Unfortunately it doesn't mention a solution. As it is for Firefox 18, maybe some workaround has arrived in the meantime.